# Upgrade Azure Devops Server 2019 to Azure Devops Server 2020

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2020

I am trying to Upgrade Azure Devops Server 2019 to Azure Devops Server 2020
looking for some best practice
Thanks

[image]

```
[1040:2C34][2021-04-02T03:04:37]i000: MUX:  Online feed url authoring not found
[1040:2C34][2021-04-02T03:04:37]i000: MUX:  Warning Block: ProcessBlock : Please close the Azure DevOps Server Administration Console before continuing.
[1040:2C34][2021-04-02T03:04:37]i000: MUX:  Online feed url authoring not found
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020

> The general upgrade process is as follows:
>
> [image]

Also, check the following documentation which  covers a typical Azure DevOps Server (TFS) upgrade scenario:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/walkthrough?view=tfs-2015

Comment: Dong : i have downloaded "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/633b160b-5f28-43e3-a186-7651ccb43eb6/9d592d8a0932abffe608759738f805be/azuredevopsserver2020.exe" and tried running its giving an error "Please close the Azure DevOps Server Administration Console before continuing."

Comment: Have you checked your environment? Does it meet Azure Devops Server 2020 requirement? I'd like to suggest you do a dry run of your upgrade in a pre-production environment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/pre-production?view=azure-devops-2020. The error you met indicated the Administration Console is still under running.

Comment: Administration Console was opened in my colluge system, after clsoing the azuredevopssserver.exe installter executed and replaces azuredevops server2019, now i have azure devops server 2020 administration console and i have use wizard to configure azure devopsserver 2020 with old db

Comment: I am stuck  with database configuration , i think i have to take backup of the old database ,as if i use the existing database there is chance azuredevopsserver2020 overwrite some info

Comment: I was taking a look to https://dev.to/rajh24/updating-to-the-latest-version-of-azure-devops-server-from-tfs-2018-5a29

Comment: Does your database version meet the requirement of azuredevopsserver2020? Please follow the steps in the link I provided to prepare the environment and upgrade the server.

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: I was abel to Successful upgrade Azure Devops Server 2019 to Azure Devops Server 2020